# What is the difference between ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on the Camera API and am confused between the following two Intents:

> ```
> ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
> ```
>
> *> added in API level 3*
>
> ```
> String ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
> ```
>
> Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application
>   capture a video and return it.
>
> The caller may pass in an extra EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY to control the
>   video quality.
>
> The caller may pass in an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where the
>   video is written. If EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present the video will be
>   written to the standard location for videos, and the Uri of that
>   location will be returned in the data field of the Uri. As of
>   LOLLIPOP, this uri can also be supplied through setClipData(ClipData).
>   If using this approach, you still must supply the uri through the
>   EXTRA_OUTPUT field for compatibility with old applications. If you
>   don't set a ClipData, it will be copied there for you when calling
>   startActivity(Intent).

---

> ```
> INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA
> ```
>
> added in API level 3
>
> ```
> String INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA
> ```
>
> The name of the Intent action used to launch a camera in video mode.
>
> Constant Value: "android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA"

If I want to capture a Video from a Camera App, I would of course launch the Camera in the Video mode but both Intents seems to do that. How are they different?

Answer (score 0):

There are two major differences.

1. With `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, you can specify a destination folder.
2. With `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, your user can't change the camera mode other than the video camera mode.

And, also, if I recall correctly, your activity can receive the `onActivityResult` callback only with `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`.